# String a command after a command that ends in & - EX: nohup > log & && rm log

Tags: shell, command-line, control-flow

So I guess there is actually two parts to this question, because I don't want the RM to go untill the nohup command has finished, but the problem is, I love to string together commands, but my nohup command ends in &! Not sure what to do!

Example desired command

```
nohup sudo rsync -av --progress --remove-source-files /Completed/* /Movies  > transfer.nohup & && rm /Completed/* -R
```

Comment: curious to me that you have to do your trailing `rm` command after using rsync's --remove-source-files option; what's left in /Completed that needs to be removed?

Comment: @JeffSchaller  It removes the Files, but not the folders!

Comment: @adonis, It is required for nohup to run in the background!

Comment: To adonis' point, you are undoing the & effect, so why not remove it.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, that I am tying up the Shell by waiting for the second command, so its not running in the background, is that what you mean?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers yes.

Answer (score 3):

You might have to `wait` for an answer.

```
$ date; nohup sleep 7 & wait && echo xxx; date
Thu Oct  1 19:39:24 UTC 2015
[1] 16199
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
[1]+  Done                    nohup sleep 7
xxx
Thu Oct  1 19:39:31 UTC 2015
$
```

Otherwise, a shell wrapper could also do the trick, and would not tie up the shell with a `wait`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
rsync ...
rm ...
```

Then just `nohup` that shell script, which will do the copy and then the rm.

Comment: The wait doesn't work in this case, because I don't know the time, although I could set it ridiculously high, I will try the script tho!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers the 7 in the example was just that -- an example. The wait command will wait for your backgrounded process to complete.

Comment: so if i put no number, it will just wait?!